# Transfer player's data from scene to scene

Tags: unity, c#

so I have a little project where I have 3 scenes - gameplay one with player and it's script, main menu with 2 buttons "Play" and "Shop" and shop scene with 2 buttons "Buy HP" and "Buy Speed". So I want to have an opportunity to change some stats on player from shop scene. I used PlayerPrefs for this and setted values in Start method of player's script.

```
[SerializeField] private int maxHP = 1;
[SerializeField] private int hp = 0;
[SerializeField] private float attackTimer = 2f;

void Start()
    {
        if(maxHP == 1) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("maxHP", maxHP);
        }
        else {
            if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("maxHP") != null) {
                maxHP = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("maxHP");
            }
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("attackCD", attackTimer);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        currentAttackTimer = attackTimer;
        hp = maxHP;
    }
```

so player's Start() method looks like this. Cause attackTimer is changing in the same way, I will put only maxHP as an example:

```
public void BuyHP() {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("maxHP") < 5) {
            int tmpHP = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("maxHP");
            tmpHP++;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("maxHP", tmpHP);
            hpText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("maxHP").ToString() + "/5";
        }
    }
```

this script is on button, it works to change value up to 5 times and rewrite it in "maxHP" key, but at the start of a gameplay scene I have maxHP = 1 anyway. Can somebody help me out and explain, mby I don't really know how PlayerPrefs works? Thx in advance

Comment: You want to know how playerprefs are working or how to transfer the data from one scene to another? One is like a registry key, storing values that are lasting even after you end the game, for the other one you could take a look at `DontDestroyOnLoad`

Comment: I want to transfer data, used PlayerPrefs cause my friend said that I can use it to solve my problem

Comment: You may be interested in [past Q&A about sharing/transferring data between scenes in Untiy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+between+scenes)

Comment: @DMGregory ok, thx, will check this out

Answer (score 0):

I used static class to transfer data, thx @DMGregory for the link - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+between+scenes